# net.LookUpHost() outputs no such host after using os.Hostname()

Tags: macos, go, bonjour, mdns

I'm currently attempting to learn the programming language go and stubbled across this weird problem. 
I've created a simple go application that gets the Hostname succesfully, which I then try to get my addresses with. Finally I iterate over these addresses.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    name, error := os.Hostname()
    fmt.Println("Name: " + name)
    fmt.Print("Error: ")
    fmt.Println(error)

    addrs, err := net.LookupHost(name)

    fmt.Println(addrs)

    fmt.Println(err)

    for indx, addr := range addrs {
        fmt.Println("Address number " + strconv.Itoa(indx) + ": " + addr)
    }
}
```

The output of this is the following:

```
Name: My-macbook.local
Error: <nil>
[]
lookup My-macbook.local: no such host
```

I also tried using net.LookUpIP(name), which resulted in the same. I'm connected to the internet and I checked that I had an ip address in system preferences -> network. I am currently on a Macbook Pro with macOS Sierra.

My friend ran the exact same code with the exact same version of go and had two addresses returned so do I have something preventing me from seeing my Ip addresses. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: This just means that your system's concept of its own hostname is not reflected in DNS.

Comment: If your goal is to determine your machine's IP address, that's also not especially straight forward, as a machine may have multiple IP addresse.

Comment: Is there a way to change my system's concept of its own hostname so it will reflect my DNS?

Comment: That depends on too many things for a single answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `.local` address you are trying to resolve is not a regular DNS entry, its a special one for local networks. It has several names such as `bonjour`, `avahi` etc. The RFC calls it `mdns` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local, see also [dns service discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#DNS-SD).

According to the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/) you should try to set this environment variable `export GODEBUG=netdns=cgo` in order to force the golang dns resolver to call for the system libraries. Indeed the pure golang DNS resolver [does not resolve mdns](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3297).

You could also try an alternate mdns golang implementation such as https://github.com/hashicorp/mdns

Note also that the net package provides a `DefaultResolver` variable that you may override with a custom implementation to resolve `\.local$`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I attempted the export GODEBUG=netdns=cgo, but this didn't have any impact.

Is there any way to have my hostname reflect in my DNS as @Flimzy mentioned?

Overriding the net package and using alternative implementations just seems weird 
seeing as my friend's macbook had no issues with this.

Comment: Assuming your friend can resolve your hostname, it is not a problem of your computer announcing the dns, its a problem of the golang dns resolver implementation not being able, on your computer, to resolve the dns. Maybe you and your friend have not installed golang the same way, or some libraries. IDK macos sorry. FTR mdns let you announce any dns, you might try to go down that way.

Comment: can you show the output of `GODEBUG=netdns=1 go run main.go` and `GODEBUG=netdns=cgo+1 go run main.go` ?

Comment: GODEBUG=netdns=1 go run main.go outputs
`Name: My-Macbook.local
Error: <nil>
go package net: using cgo DNS resolver
[]
lookup My-Macbook.local: no such host`

GODEBUG=netdns=cgo+1 go run main.go outputs
`Name: My-Macbook.local
Error: <nil>
go package net: using cgo DNS resolver
[]
lookup My-Macbook.local: no such host`